# The importance of yellow warnings in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Of course I know there are yellow warnings that they are important. For example if we use the following code we will get a yellow warning, because we did not use the `show()` method.

```
Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"Warning",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

But also there are yellow warnings that I do not know they are important or not. For example if I create a button in visual Editor in the android studio, the android studio says to me that I should use the `String` resources for naming the button.

If I do not use the `string` resources for naming the button does it make disruption in the program?

**The second case:**

When I want to use the `try{} catch{}` in my code and if I do not use a code in the block of the `catch`, as the result the android studio says to me that the block of the `catch` is empty. Is filling  the block of the `catch` really important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first part of the question: it does not disrupt your program. Hold your <strike>mouse</strike>cursor on the yellow line for approx. a second and a pop-up appears with the explanation. From the top of my head, I think Android Studio warns you, as you are hard coding text that will be shown to the user. When you use string resources instead, it is really easy to translate the displayed text. 
You can read more about String resources here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

For the second part, it sounds like you need to work on your programming skills (not to be rude, but I consider that as one of the basic things in programming land). You wrap code in a try/catch block, as you expect that your code inside the try block might throw an exception. So, if your program ends up in a catch block, you probably want to let the user know in some way, or at least log something, so you know what is going wrong. Read more about catch blocks here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html.